# SVN Error : is not a working copy

Tags: maven, svn, plugins, release

I having one problem but i don't know solve this, I search all web, however nothing can help me.

I'm using "mvn release:prepare" to compile one project in my local repository, but happens the  following error : " The svn command failed.
                    Command output:
svn: E155007: 'C:\foundation\pom.xml' is not a working copy ".

This project contains submodules, the foundation is principal module of project, the submodules are core,presentation,security, these submodules contain a pom.xml that points to configuration from parent pom in module foundation.

Previously happened the same error in pom.xml from core module, because the version tag was different from version tag in parent pom.xml, I solved this put 3.2.2.1-SNAPSHOT in all submodules,but now get error in pom.xml from root module that is foundation.

Help me , I have not any idea to solve this.

Att;

Comment: What SVN command is failing, SVN status? Where can you find the .svn directory?

Comment: I don't know the command failed, not display in screen cmd.

Comment: I suspect that you're seeing this due to a mismatch between the version of SVN that mvn is using and that your working copy is created with.  Working copy formats changed between 1.6 and 1.7 in a way that can result in this sort of error.

Comment: Having a -X output of your Maven log would probably help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your .svn or .git dir is corrupt, as you can check in this response
[SVN Error - Not a working copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374313/svn-error-not-a-working-copy)
try with a fresh checkout as the above response recomend

if you are using maven release prepare perform maybe you need to add detailed relative dir at maven release plugin as mention this post
[maven release plugin, git, and the pom's not at the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558785/maven-release-plugin-git-and-the-poms-not-at-the-top)