# "Is not a working copy" error when trying to commit SVN

Tags: svn, netbeans

I'm so confused about this.. I think there's something missing in the error that could help, but I'm not sure.

When trying to commit to an SVN repository, NetBeans is returning this error:

> org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: E155007: {0} is not a
>   working copy

Upon reading up, I've tried several things, including Updating, Cleaning Up, and Checking out.. (checking out actually screwed things up a fair bit and duplicated my project).

But all of them, still return the error. I believe the {0} part is meant to be showing a file that isn't under version control, is that correct?

Not sure where to go from here, and I can't make any more commits. If possible, I don't want to have to just abandon, and create a new project and SVN repository from scratch.

My Netbeans SVN properties shows this:
[image]

Comment: I don't wish to sound rude, but whoever downvoted, please leave a comment as to why.. it would be really helpful!

Comment: What does NetBeans say about your svn settings (Team > Versioning Info)?

Comment: As far as I can tell they all seem correct and normal. What should I be looking for specifically?

Comment: I'm not really sure, but it might be a general svn problem, not just NetBeans (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374313/svn-error-not-a-working-copy).

Comment: I really wish people would comment when downvoting. It should be compulsory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with NetBeans that somehow it tries to run SVN commands against something that is not a Subversion working copy. All Subversion commands have to be run against repository URLs or against local working copy. NetBeans in your case somehow lost the connection with the working copy. `{0}` in the error clearly indicates that something is wrong with NetBeans, it does not pass path to your working copy.

If you run `svn commit -m "Commit Message"` when in the working copy, the commit should work fine without any errors.

I'd suggest reporting this problem to someone at NetBeans since this looks like a bug. As a workaround commit through CLI and checkout a new & clean working copy of your project to a new location and make sure that the commit and other commands work with it without any problems.

Comment: Thanks for that. How do I commit via CLI in NetBeans?

Comment: @Lee CLI means command-line interface implying that you should run `svn commit` in the command prompt, not in NetBeans IDE.

Comment: I know what CLI means, but the way you were explaining, I thought there was a feature inside NetBeans to do this. Can I run SVN commands directly in the CMD prompt then?

Comment: @lee yes. Just make sure that you actually have `svn` client properly installed.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this when my project wasn't set up correctly on the SVN server.  Make sure to check-out your project, merge as needed, THEN commit.